# difference between using and not using @modelAttribute in method parameter

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring mvc and have seen examples where folks use `@ModelAttribute("form") Person person` in method parameter and some who just do `(Person person)`. what is the difference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ModelAttribute` allows you to specify the name of the model attribute. When parameter doesn't have this annotation, a decapitalized class name is used as an attribute name, i.e. `Person p` -> "person".

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify `@ModelAttribute` in this situation, then Spring will infer the presence of one. In this case, it would infer `@ModelAttribute("person")`. The argument is the name of the model.

If you don't want the default name, or if you just want to be explicit about saying that the `Person` parameter is a model attribute, then you should specify `@ModelAttribute`, with or without the explicit name.